# Decrease woocommerce cart count if specific product is in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

does anyone know a possibility/function to decrease the woocommerce cart count, if a specific product is added? The product itself is just a configurator for add-ons and doesn't need to be count.

Hope anyone can help.

Comment: Check the filter solution - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71880209/modify-get-cart-contents-count-to-count-only-specific-product-ids-in-woocomm. In foreach check the product you want to exclude and recount items in cart.

Comment: I found the answer to my own question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43498002/how-to-remove-a-product-or-category-from-cart-count